# How to create pandas.date_range() for each row from column "start_date" and column "end_date"?

Tags: pandas, date, date-range

I have a df like:

```
id | start_date | end_date  | price
1  | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-3 | 1
1  | 2020-10-03 | 2020-10-4 | 1
2  | 2020-10-04 | 2020-10-6 | 2
3  | 2020-10-05 | 2020-10-5 | 3
```

Columns "start_date" and "end_date" are datetime64[ns].

I want to create a "date" column from the date range.

Easiest way is creating a pandas.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="D"), then using .explode().

End result should look like:

```
id | start_date | end_date  | price | date
1  | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-3 | 1     | 2020-10-01
1  | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-3 | 1     | 2020-10-02
1  | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-3 | 1     | 2020-10-03
1  | 2020-10-03 | 2020-10-4 | 1     | 2020-10-03
1  | 2020-10-03 | 2020-10-4 | 1     | 2020-10-04
2  | 2020-10-04 | 2020-10-6 | 2     | 2020-10-04
2  | 2020-10-04 | 2020-10-6 | 2     | 2020-10-05
2  | 2020-10-04 | 2020-10-6 | 2     | 2020-10-06
3  | 2020-10-05 | 2020-10-5 | 3     | 2020-10-05
```

Tried so far:

```
df["daterange"] = pd.date_range(df["start_date"], df["end_date"])
```

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [0 2020-10-01
> 1 2020-10-01

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    df["daterange"] = pd.date_range(start=row.start_date, end=row.end_date)
```

> ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (9)

**Lambdas, apply, melt, etc. is way too slow for my dataframe size and is not useable!**

/edit

Fastet method I found so far:

```
https://github.com/Garve/scikit-bonus
skbonus.pandas.preprocessing.DateTimeExploder(
        "date",
        start_column="start_date",
        end_column="end_date",
        frequency="d",
        drop=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fasted method I've found so far:

```
https://github.com/Garve/scikit-bonus
from skbonus.pandas.preprocessing import DateTimeExploder
df = DateTimeExploder(
        "date",
        start_column="start_date",
        end_column="end_date",
        frequency="d",
        drop=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df["daterange"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.start_date, x.end_date), axis=1)
df = df.explode('daterange').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   id  start_date   end_date  price  daterange
0   1  2020-10-01  2020-10-3      1 2020-10-01
1   1  2020-10-01  2020-10-3      1 2020-10-02
2   1  2020-10-01  2020-10-3      1 2020-10-03
3   1  2020-10-03  2020-10-4      1 2020-10-03
4   1  2020-10-03  2020-10-4      1 2020-10-04
5   2  2020-10-04  2020-10-6      2 2020-10-04
6   2  2020-10-04  2020-10-6      2 2020-10-05
7   2  2020-10-04  2020-10-6      2 2020-10-06
8   3  2020-10-05  2020-10-5      3 2020-10-05
```

Alternative:

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.start_date, r.end_date)) for r in df.itertuples()])
s = pd.Series(s.index, s)

df = df.join(s.rename('daterange')).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   id  start_date   end_date  price  daterange
0   1  2020-10-01  2020-10-3      1 2020-10-01
1   1  2020-10-01  2020-10-3      1 2020-10-02
2   1  2020-10-01  2020-10-3      1 2020-10-03
3   1  2020-10-03  2020-10-4      1 2020-10-03
4   1  2020-10-03  2020-10-4      1 2020-10-04
5   2  2020-10-04  2020-10-6      2 2020-10-04
6   2  2020-10-04  2020-10-6      2 2020-10-05
7   2  2020-10-04  2020-10-6      2 2020-10-06
8   3  2020-10-05  2020-10-5      3 2020-10-05
```

Comment: Thanks, that took 224 seconds for my dataframe which is way too slow sadly.

Comment: @Vega - It is long time, I know. Can you test alternative, please?

Comment: alternative method took 282 seconds. Thanks for the help.

Found scikit-bonus with DateTimeExploder(), that took only 148 seconds.