# How to add lag to time series data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with tv spot data per product id:

```
  | start_date | end_date   | id | f1  | f2
0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 1  | 111 | 222
1 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-07 | 1  | 111 | 222
2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 3  | 333 | 444
3 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-07 | 3  | 555 | 666
```

Now I want to add lag from 0 to 2 days to use as features in a forecast model.

The date range "start_date" + "end_date" should then be exploded into a "date" column so that I have a "date" column instead of a date range.

But I have no idea how I can achieve that.

End result should look like:

```
  | date       | id | f1_lag_0 | f2_lag_0 | f1_lag_1 | f2_lag_1 | f1_lag_2 | f2_lag_2
0 | 2020-01-01 | 1  | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
1 | 2020-01-02 | 1  | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
2 | 2020-01-03 | 1  | NaN      | NaN      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
3 | 2020-01-04 | 1  | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | 111      | 222
0 | 2020-01-05 | 1  | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
1 | 2020-01-06 | 1  | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
2 | 2020-01-07 | 1  | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
3 | 2020-01-08 | 1  | NaN      | NaN      | 111      | 222      | 111      | 222
4 | 2020-01-09 | 1  | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | 111      | 222
0 | 2020-01-01 | 3  | 333      | 444      | 333      | 444      | 333      | 444
1 | 2020-01-02 | 3  | 333      | 444      | 333      | 444      | 333      | 444
2 | 2020-01-03 | 3  | NaN      | NaN      | 333      | 444      | 333      | 444
3 | 2020-01-04 | 3  | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | 333      | 444
0 | 2020-01-05 | 3  | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666
1 | 2020-01-06 | 3  | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666
2 | 2020-01-07 | 3  | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666
3 | 2020-01-08 | 3  | NaN      | NaN      | 555      | 666      | 555      | 666
4 | 2020-01-09 | 3  | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | NaN      | 555      | 666
```

Code for creating dummy df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start_date": [
            "2020-01-01",
            "2020-01-05",
            "2020-01-01",
            "2020-01-06",
        ],
        "end_date": [
            "2020-01-02",
            "2020-01-07",
            "2020-01-02",
            "2020-01-07"
        ],
        "id": ["1", "1", "3", "3"],
        "feature1": ["111", "111", "333", "555"],
        "feature2": ["222", "222", "444", "666"],
    }
)
```

Comment: So need something faster like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66689956/2901002) ?

Comment: No. "I want to add lag from 0 to 7 days" for each tv spot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#list of features
cols = ['feature1','feature2']
#convert both columnsto datetimes
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])

#add new days to difference
N = 1
dif = df['end_date'].sub(df['start_date']).dt.days + 1 + N
#repeat index by difference 
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(dif)].copy()
#add tiemdeltas to start datetimes
df['start_date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
```

Last use shift per groups:

```
for j, i in enumerate(range(2, -1, -1)):
    df[[f'f1_lag_{j}', f'f2_lag_{j}']] = df.groupby(level=0)[cols].shift(-i)
    
df = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
        .drop('end_date', axis=1)
        .rename(columns={'start_date':'date'})
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
print (df)
         date id f1_lag_0 f2_lag_0 f1_lag_1 f2_lag_1 f1_lag_2 f2_lag_2
0  2020-01-01  a      111      222      111      222      111      222
1  2020-01-02  a      111      222      111      222      111      222
2  2020-01-03  a      NaN      NaN      111      222      111      222
3  2020-01-04  a      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      111      222
4  2020-01-05  a      111      222      111      222      111      222
5  2020-01-06  a      111      222      111      222      111      222
6  2020-01-07  a      111      222      111      222      111      222
7  2020-01-08  a      NaN      NaN      111      222      111      222
8  2020-01-09  a      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      111      222
9  2020-01-01  b      333      444      333      444      333      444
10 2020-01-02  b      333      444      333      444      333      444
11 2020-01-03  b      NaN      NaN      333      444      333      444
12 2020-01-04  b      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      333      444
13 2020-01-06  b      555      666      555      666      555      666
14 2020-01-07  b      555      666      555      666      555      666
15 2020-01-08  b      NaN      NaN      555      666      555      666
16 2020-01-09  b      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      555      666
```